# Jenkinsfile: How to call a groovy function with named arguments

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a simple Declarative Pipeline with function inside. How to correctly use named arguments for a function?

```
def getInputParams(param1='a', param2='b') {
    echo "param1 is ${param1}, param2 is ${param2}"
}

pipeline {
...
...
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                getInputParams(param1='x', param2='y')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot understand why named params become null in function?

```
[Pipeline] echo
param1 is null, param2 is null
...
```

Well, I'm able to call function like `getInputParams('x', 'y')`, but it's not human readable (arguments amount may increase in future)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Groovy is executed inside the Jenkinsfile so you have to follow its syntax for named arguments.

```
foo(name: 'Michael', age: 24)
def foo(Map args) { "${args.name}: ${args.age}" }
```

---

Quote from [Groovy's named arguments](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.5.0/html/documentation/#_named_arguments):

> Like constructors, normal methods can also be called with named
> arguments. They need to receive the parameters as a map. In the method
> body, the values can be accessed as in normal maps (map.key).

```
def getInputParams(Map map) {
    echo "param1 is ${map.param1}, param2 is ${map.param2}"
}

pipeline {
...
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                getInputParams(param1: 'x', param2: 'y')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I want to use named arguments, it's more human readable, when you have multiple input parameters for function.

Comment: Sorry I mised it. I added it to the answer.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Note that Jenkins still uses a Groovy version 2.x (somewhere around 2.4 or 2.5), so the latest Groovy 3.x and 4.x features are not available.

Answer (score -5):

If you are using groovy, use this.

```
def getInputParams(def param1, def param2) {
    println("param1 is "+ param1 + ", param2 is " + param2)
}

pipeline {
...
...
    stages {
        stage('Test) {
            steps {
                getInputParams(x, y)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey. Pls, see last paragraph in my question, I told that this way is not human readable.